# Mongoose speed up the search on multiple fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working on a search feature over mongoose documents where I have to search over 250,000 documents.
In this feature I have to add search indexes over multiple fields.
In documents some of the fields are string type,
some are multi level objects.
I have indexed all the possible fields.

At local I am having 100,000 documents and when I search over them it took around 300-400ms.
But when I search over them on server It took around 10-15 sec to respond.

The search query is conditional based but I am sharing a small code snippet.

```
   $and(

{
    $or:[
        {'field1': {$regex: re }},
        {'field2': {$regex: re }},
        {'level1.level2.value': {$regex: re }}
    ]
},
{
    $and:[ 
        {
            lowAge: {$lte: parseInt(age)}
        },
        {
            highAge: {$gte: parseInt(age)}
        },
        {
            $or:[
                {
                   gender:gender
                },
                {
                   gender:"N/A"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
 )
```

Can someone advice me that how can I speed up the process on server.

Comment: My guess would be that your server is underpowered, in terms of RAM, CPU or (probably) both. What sort of instance type are you using? Also, regular expression queries _can_ be very slow, even with indexes. Try to avoid them if possible.

Comment: any alternative you know other than regular expressions

Comment: It entirely depends on what your queries/regexes look like.

Comment: It still depends on what `re` is.

Comment: @robertkelp We have three instances in a cluster, each with 4gb memory and burstable cpu. reads should be spread out across them while writes will always go to the current primary.

Comment: In that case, 10-15 seconds seems like a lot, esp since you're getting sub-second times locally with not _that_ much less documents. I'd check logfiles to see if anything points towards a reason for that. Also, make sure that the indexes are actually there.

Answer (score 0):

To speed further more, you can use the text index.

But text index comes with the following Storage Requirements and Performance Costs

- Text indexes can be large. They contain one index entry for each unique post-stemmed word in each indexed field for each document inserted.
- Building a text index is very similar to building a large multi-key index and will take longer than building a simple ordered (scalar) index on the same data.
  When building a large text index on an existing collection, ensure that you have a sufficiently high limit on open file descriptors. See the recommended settings.
- Text indexes will impact insertion throughput because MongoDB must add an index entry for each unique post-stemmed word in each indexed field of each new source document.
- Additionally, text indexes do not store phrases or information about the proximity of words in the documents. As a result, phrase queries will run much more effectively when the entire collection fits in RAM.

Please see the below references

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_text_search.htm

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have used mongoose text search in other collections and as I think it works on the fields of type string. Now I have to search over the field like this, so can I define text index over the code I just added in a new edit.
 "Diseases": [{"Disease": [{"value": "Cystic Fibrosis"}],"name": "CG"},
              {"Disease": [{"value": "Cystic xx"}],"name": "CI"},
              {"Disease": [{"value": "Cystic xx"}],"name": "CI"}
              {"Disease": [{"value": "Cystic yys"}],"name": "CI"}
             ],

Comment: Yes, Text search only works on type string. Index we need to create it once, so try creating it in the mongo shell and it would be used in your search queries while you are executing find query in mongo shell/mongoose or by any other means.

Comment: @varun - You can remove the `$or` condition for gender, since it can take only 3 values Male, Female or N/A and you have included all these options in your query. So $or operation is not needed, since we are picking up the record in both the cases whether the gender is present or not.